# Transaction for Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to `sum` and make `order grandtotal - sum(invoice grandtotal)`

This is my query

```
Select 
    co.documentno, co.grandtotal,
    ci.documentno, sum(ci.grandtotal),
    co.grandtotal - sum(ci.grandtotal) as total
From 
    c_order co, c_invoice ci
Where
    co.c_order_id = ci.c_order_id and
    co.docstatus not in ('RE','VO','IN') and
    ci.docstatus not in ('RE','VO','IN')
Group by    
    co.documentno, co.grandtotal,
    ci.documentno, co.c_order_id, ci.c_invoice_id
Order by 
    co.c_order_id, ci.c_invoice_id
```

I want to show `null` in invoice because order can have **outstanding** invoice, and my query doesn't give me the expected result

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, could you add some sample data and the expected output for that data?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join you tables to get a null value

```
    Select 
        co.documentno, co.grandtotal,
        ci.documentno, sum(ci.grandtotal),
        co.grandtotal - sum(ci.grandtotal) as total
    From 
        c_order co
   Left Join
      c_invoice ci
    On
      co.c_order_id = ci.c_order_id
    Where
        co.c_order_id = ci.c_order_id and
        co.docstatus not in ('RE','VO','IN') and
        ci.docstatus not in ('RE','VO','IN')
    Group by    
        co.documentno, co.grandtotal,
        ci.documentno, co.c_order_id, ci.c_invoice_id
    Order by 
        co.c_order_id, ci.c_invoice_id
```